# how to get access to private members of nested class?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Background: I have enclosed (parent) class E with nested class N with several instances of N in E. In the enclosed (parent) class I am doing some calculations and I am setting the values for each instance of nested class. Something like this:

```
n1.field1 = ...;
n1.field2 = ...;
n1.field3 = ...;
n2.field1 = ...;
...
```

It is one big eval method (in parent class). My intention is -- since all calculations are in parent class (they cannot be done per nested instance because it would make code more complicated) -- make the setters only available to parent class and getters public.

And now there is a problem:

- when I make the setters private, parent class cannot acces them
- when I make them public, everybody can change the values
- and C# does not have friend concept
- I cannot pass values in constructor because lazy evaluation mechanism is used (so the instances have to be created when referencing them -- I create all objects and the calculation is triggered on demand)

I am stuck -- how to do this (limit access up to parent class, no more, no less)?

---

*I suspect I'll get answer-question first -- "but why you don't split the evaluation per each field" -- so I answer this by example: how do you calculate min and max value of a collection? In a fast way? The answer is -- in one pass. This is why I have one eval function which does calculations and sets all fields at once.*

Comment: Is internal keyword not enough?

Comment: You don't trust your coworkers?

Comment: "Trust" should be outside the scope of coding. Either the code is rock-solid or it is not and you have to put extra trust in it. I prefer the first :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restrict access to nested class member to enclosing class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664793/how-to-restrict-access-to-nested-class-member-to-enclosing-class)

Comment: That comment from Eric Lippert is surprising and alarming, and suggests why C#'s access rules are so bolluxed. Access has nothing whatsoever to do with trust/security ... it is entirely a matter of encapsulation. The members of nested classes *should* always be accessible to the classes that enclose them. That they aren't in C# is bad language design. And the stunning irony is that the language enforces lack of "trust" of the outer class by the inner class.

Comment: I'm shocked by Eric Lippert's comment as well. I don't even trust myself, never mind my coworkers! I use accessibility levels to guarantee the state an object can possibly be in. If you rely on trust, why have accessibility levels at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's possible for you to put the parent and child classes in another assembly, you can make use of `internal` for the setters. That's generally how this is dealt with in the wild.

***EDIT***:

[Thomas Levesque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816961/how-to-get-access-to-private-members-of-nested-class/2817005#2817005) gave me an idea:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        E myE = new E();

        Console.WriteLine("E.N1.Field1 = " + myE.N1.Field1);
        Console.WriteLine("E.N2.Field1 = " + myE.N2.Field1);
    }

    public interface IN
    {
        int Field1 { get; }
    }

    public class E
    {
        private N _n1 = new N();
        private N _n2 = new N();

        public E()
        {
            _n1.Field1 = 42;
            _n2.Field1 = 23;
        }

        public IN N1
        {
            get { return _n1; }
        }

        public IN N2
        {
            get { return _n2; }
        }

        private class N : IN
        {
            private int _field1;

            public int Field1
            {
                get { return _field1; }
                set { _field1 = value; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on how you need to expose the child class `N`, this could work.

Comment: Thank you, but it is a single file, not that big, so it seems like a bit of overkill setting this separate assembly.

Comment: Updated my answer based upon Thomas Levesque's answer.

Comment: Beauty (the interface can be nested). THANK YOU!

Comment: You variation of Thomas Levesque's answer seems a bit odd to me. You make the nested class private and the interface public (while TL's code does vica versa). What's the point in this? I thought the whole point was to give the outer class access to the nested class' private fields, while exposing the nested class to the outer world. In your case no special privileges are given to the outer class, it can get access to Field1 like anyone else through the interface. And if you want to keep nested class private, interface might not be needed at all, you can go with properties.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. You should remove the mention of "internal" at the top since it's not relevant and I almost skipped the answer because of it. A `private` nested class with a `public` interface is a very intuitive way to solve this sort of problem.

Answer (score 57):

You could declare inside `E` a private interface `IN`, explicitly implemented by `N`. This interface would expose the members of `N` accessible only by `E` :

```
public class E
{
    public void Foo()
    {
      IN n = new N();
      n.Field1 = 42;
    }

    public class N : IN
    {
        private int _field1;

        int IN.Field1
        {
            get { return _field1; }
            set { _field1 = value; }
        }
    }

    private interface IN
    {
        int Field1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Interface cannot be made private because I won't read the values outside the parent class (I need public getters), and once it is public I can also use setters publicly.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer... the `IN` interface is never intended to be public. It is only a way for the nested class to expose properties only to the containing class. You can also create public getters in `N` if you need them

Comment: If the interface is private it is not available outside the parent class.

Comment: well, yes, that's the point... that way, only the parent class can set the nested class private fields

Comment: This answer is genius.  Huge +1!

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative is to leave the members you wish to be private public **if your (nested) class is private.** If fields of private class is public, its only going to be exposed to the enclosing class.

```
public class E
{
    public void Foo()
    {
      IN n = new N();
      n.field1 = 42;
    }

    class N : IN
    {
        public int _field1;
    }
}
```

Now `N` is only visible to `E`, so `n._field1` being public only matters to `E`, and you're safe..

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but here goes a possible solution that doesn't use interfaces.

You can have a static function in the inner class which sets up delegates in the outer class, like so:

```
public class Outer {
    private delegate void _operateDlg(Inner inner, bool value);
    private static _operateDlg _validate;

    static Outer() {
        Inner.Init();
    }

    public void Set(Inner inner, bool value) {
        _validate(inner, value);
    }

    public class Inner {
        public bool IsValid {get; private set; }
        public static void Init() {
            Outer._validate += delegate(Inner i, bool value) {
                i.IsValid = value;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

You can put all kinds of different delegates in the outer class that you assign with the Inner.Init() method, such as methods which return an instance of the Inner class through a private constructor or getters/setters of a particular field.

If you don't mind having an extra Init() static function in your inner class, then this doesn't have to change. But if you don't want the Init() method to be visible, you can use reflection to call it:

```
using System.Reflection;

public class Outer {
    private delegate void _operateDlg(Inner inner, bool value);
    private static _operateDlg _validate;

    static Outer() {
        typeof(Inner).GetMethod("Init",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(null, null);
    }

    public void Set(Inner inner, bool value) {
        _validate(inner, value);
    }

    public class Inner {
        public bool IsValid {get; private set; }
        private static void Init() {
            Outer._validate = delegate(Inner i, bool value) {
                i.IsValid = value;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I know that one could use Reflection to bypass private access restrictions anyway, but using it just to call one single Init() method which then assigns the appropriate delegates is a much cleaner and more versatile solution in my opinion. The alternative would be calling reflection for every single delegate you might want to create, and even then there could be limitations (such as the inability to create delegates to constructors).

The above solution not only supports wrapping constructors, but it will only use Reflection once in the lifetime of a program, so there shouldn't be a noticeable performance penalty other than the fact that you're using delegates to achieve what should have been allowed as direct access in the first place. I don't know why C# doesn't support this, and I can't think of a good reason why it doesn't.

Answer (score -3):

make the fields "protected internal"

if the nested classes are private you could use obly "internal" to those fields.

Comment: Won't the fields be exposed to whole assembly?

Comment: in case of "internal field and private class": no because the class is private.

the other case: yes it would. but the own assembly should be under your control. usually that is not a problem.

Comment: Actually it is always a problem -- one year later, you can have the same best intention, but you could forget the design. The code should reflect the design, not comments or wishes.

Comment: `protected internal` means protected OR internal ... broader access than just internal. In any case, `protected` is irrelevant here since the nested class has no subclasses.