# How to make a class accessible by only ONE other class without Class Nesting?

Tags: c#

I have given the following example of code:

```
public static class A
{
    private static B _b;

    public static B GetB
    {
        get
        {
            if(_b == null)
            {
                _b = B.load();
            }
            return _b;
        }

    }

    public static void Save()
    {
        if(_b == null)
        {
            _b = B.load();
        }
        _b.Save()
    }
}

public class B
{
    public string Value{ get; set;}

    public void Save()
    {
        //value is being save to somewhere
    }

    public static B load()
    {
        B b = new B();

        // .....
        //b.Value is loaded from somewhere
        // ......
        return b;
    }
}
```

The next following is that I need to solve:

```
A.GetB.Value = "value";  // OK
B.Load().Value = "value";  // I need to prevent this
```

Above two lines of code does exactly same stuff but...

**B.Load().Value** should be inaccessible from any other place except for in Class A

Please let me know if anyone have an idea...

Thanks,

Fivee

Comment: What is the reason you can't use nesting? That seems like the best/only way to do it.

Comment: To me this sounds like `A` and `B` should maybe not be separate classes.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something similar to a singleton class?

Comment: @Jashaszun The actual code length of class B is huge.... that I didn't want to implement into another huge size class A.. and I'm curious as well

Comment: @CompuChip - maybe, or that B should be split into B1 and B2. Without more context it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @john That's what I initially thought to do.. but also class B needed to be accessible from only class A

Comment: B cannot be static if you want to create an instance of it.

Comment: I just noticed that you designated class `B` as `static`. How does that work?

Comment: @Maarten Oh wow you beat me to it...

Comment: Yes, way too much `static` all around.

Comment: Just change  `B.Load()` to `internal`. That should be enough encapsulation, you can find/control calls inside one assembly by hand.

Comment: @Maarten I know static cannot be instantiated and inherited, sorry that was mistake when I was converting my project to simple code example... sorry again.. I will fix it from my question

Comment: @HenkHolterman yeah, depending on the situation. However, this strictness about `B` _not_ being accessible from anywhere _except_ `A` tells me that there is a flaw in the design which _may_ be fixed by some cool language feature (like `friend` classes in C++) but probably better addressed on a higher level.

Answer (score 6):

Basically what you are trying to do is to not nest class B inside class A, and still have class A have an exclusive access to Bs fields. If A and B are independent classes, this is against encapsulation.

You are looking for [friend classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class). These types of classes are allowed in C++. C# does not support friend classes and the closest thing we have to friend classes are friend assemblies. See this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

So if you really want that feature, you need to make them nested as others suggested.

Also, in case you wind up doing the nested class solution. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817005/2092249) is an absolutely beautiful way of handling access of a nested class's private member only to its container class. It's a little hacky but still...

Comment: Yes, the old hidden explicit interface trick. Clever but way over the top here.

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo - maybe better to explicitly link to [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2817005/60761) as it is not the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

I think that another solution might be to make `B` a `public` class (as it is already), and make `B.Load` an `internal` method. However, this would only work if you are calling `A.GetB` from another assembly (and plan on *only* this being the case).

Comment: You can't make `class B` private when `GetB` has to be public.

Comment: @Henk Oh yeah of course... if anyone has a better answer I will remove this. Until then, I will continue thinking and then will edit this.

Comment: The `internal` part is somewhat on track.