# Can this nested class constructor snippet apply to a generic class?

Tags: c#

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665586/3521178) is a highly upvoted solution to easily restrict a nested class constructor to the parent class only. I am trying to achieve exactly this but in the context of a parent class containing a nested *generic* class. Here is the original snippet for clarity:

```
public class Journal
{
  private static Func<object, JournalEntry> _newJournalEntry;

  public class JournalEntry
  {
    static JournalEntry()
    {
       _newJournalEntry = value => new JournalEntry(value);
    }
  private JournalEntry(object value)
  {
     ...
```

Here is where I'm currently at (I replaced `Func<object,JournalEntry>` with a simple `Func<JournalEntry>` for simplicity sake.)

```
public class Journal
{
    private static Func<JournalEntry> _new;

    public JournalEntry<T> NewJournalEntry<T>()
    {
        return (JournalEntry<T>)_new();            
    }

    public Journal(){}

    public class JournalEntry {}

    public class JournalEntry<T>:JournalEntry
    {
        static JournalEntry()
        {
            _new = () => new JournalEntry<T>();
        }

        private JournalEntry()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the the use case:

```
Journal j = new Journal();
Journal.JournalEntry<string> stringEntry = j.NewJournalEntry<string>();
//Fails with null reference exception
```

Per this comment from the original snippet,

> `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConst‌​ructor` can save the day. :)

I gave it a shot:

```
Journal j = new Journal();
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(Journal.JournalEntry<string>).TypeHandle);
Journal.JournalEntry<string> stringEntry = j.NewJournalEntry<string>();
//Passes
```

The above code works. The following works:

```
Journal j = new Journal();
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(Journal.JournalEntry<string>).TypeHandle);

Journal.JournalEntry<string> stringEntry = j.NewJournalEntry<string>();
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(Journal.JournalEntry<int>).TypeHandle);

Journal.JournalEntry<int> intEntry = j.NewJournalEntry<int>();
```

But attempting to ask for another `JournalEntry<string>` fails with:

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type JournalEntry[System.Int32] to type JournalEntry[System.String].

How do I solve this dilemma such that I can make any number of instances of `JournalEntry<>` with any type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach can't work, because every time the type initializer for a `JournalEntry<T>` would run (and it would run once for each `T`), it would overwrite the previous value of `_new`, breaking future usages of other `T`s.

Instead, you could do something like this:

```
public class Journal
{
    public JournalEntry<T> NewJournalEntry<T>()
    {
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(JournalEntry<T>).TypeHandle);
        return JournalEntryFactory<T>._new();
    }

    private static class JournalEntryFactory<T>
    {
        public static Func<JournalEntry<T>> _new;
    }

    public Journal() { }

    public class JournalEntry { }

    public class JournalEntry<T> : JournalEntry
    {
        static JournalEntry()
        {
            JournalEntryFactory<T>._new = () => new JournalEntry<T>();
        }

        private JournalEntry()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This way, there's a separate `_new` for each `T`.

BTW, I was the one who asked the question you referred to. For what it's worth, I think this approach is a bit hackish and error-prone. If it's possible in your case, I strongly suggest you use an interface-based approach as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1664853/98713). Here's how it would look like in your case:

```
public interface IJournalEntry<T>
{
}

public class Journal
{
    public IJournalEntry<T> NewJournalEntry<T>()
    {
        return new JournalEntry<T>();
    }

    public Journal() { }

    private class JournalEntry<T> : IJournalEntry<T>
    {
        public JournalEntry()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One particular bit of information not immediately apparent in your original accepted answer with the interface approach: make the nested class definition *private* with a *public* constructor, and miraculously only the outer class can call the constructor, as pointed out by a commenter there. Can I request a final clean snippet how you used the interface approach?

Answer (score 1):

You need multiple `new` methods. I recommend keeping them in a `Dictionary`, something like this:

```
public class Journal
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<JournalEntry>> _newFuncs = new Dictionary<System.Type, System.Func<UserQuery.Journal.JournalEntry>>();

    public JournalEntry<T> NewJournalEntry<T>()
    {
        var newFunc = _newFuncs[typeof(T)];
        return (JournalEntry<T>)newFunc();
    }

    public Journal() { }

    public class JournalEntry { }

    public class JournalEntry<T> : JournalEntry
    {
        static JournalEntry()
        {
            _newFuncs.Add(typeof(T), () => new JournalEntry<T>());
        }

        private JournalEntry()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your class in order to have `_new` as a Dictionary instead, which will allow for multiple types to be created:

```
public class Journal
{
    private static IDictionary<Type, Func<JournalEntry>> _new = new Dictionary<Type, Func<JournalEntry>>();

    public JournalEntry<T> NewJournalEntry<T>()
    {
        return (JournalEntry<T>)_new[typeof(T)]();
    }

    public Journal() { }

    public class JournalEntry { }

    public class JournalEntry<T> : JournalEntry
    {
        static JournalEntry()
        {
            _new.Add(typeof(T), () => new JournalEntry<T>());
        }

        private JournalEntry()
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't do exactly what you're asking very easily (a generic class is actually a set of classes, so you'd need several delegates for `_new`, and some way to pick one) but here is a very simple way to accomplish what you wish, without the hacky static constructor and delegate, and without using a separate interface.

Essentially we create a factory method that is protected, then create a private derivation of the class with a public version of the method.  The protected factory method can only be called from our private class.

```
public class Journal
{
    public class JournalEntry { }

    public class JournalEntry<T> : JournalEntry
    {
        protected JournalEntry()
        {
        }

        static protected JournalEntry<T> NewJournalEntry()
        {
            return new JournalEntry<T>();
        }
    }

    private class Maker<T> : JournalEntry<T>
    {
        new static public JournalEntry<T> NewJournalEntry()
        {
            return JournalEntry<T>.NewJournalEntry();
        }
    }

    public JournalEntry<T> NewJournalEntry<T>()
    {
        return Maker<T>.NewJournalEntry();
    }
}
```

You can then create a new instance like this (exactly as you ask):

```
Journal j = new Journal();
Journal.JournalEntry<string> stringEntry = j.NewJournalEntry<string>();
```

But you can't instantiate directly:

```
Journal.JournalEntry<string> wontWork = new Journal.JournalEntry<string>();  //is inaccessible due to its protection level
```