# C# - Make a private nested class visible through a public property

Tags: c#, class, static, private, public

I have the following code that does not compile:

```
public class Outer
  {
    public Inner MyField = new Inner(); //error here: "field type is less accessible than field"
    private class Inner
    {
        public string Message = "Hello";
    }
  }
```

I must be able to use the class like so:

```
var MyObject = new Outer();
Console.WriteLine(MyObject.MyField.Message); //should output "Hello"
```

"Inner" must *ONLY* be instantiable from within "Outer", so this should *NOT* be allowed:

```
var MyObject = new Outer.Inner(); //I do not want users to be able to instantiate "Inner" directly
```

Comment: Make `Inner` public.

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense, you may be looking at it the wrong way. How would a user even access that value if they don't have access to its type?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing that ? Is that just some C# brainteaser or does it reflects some actual other needs in your application?

Comment: public inner classes are generally considered a code smell. not always.

Comment: @Pac0 I made an edit to my question to be more clear

Comment: `new Outer.Inner(); //should throw an error` <= why?

Comment: @Igor because I don't want other users to be able to instantiate "Inner" directly, for encapsulation reasons

Comment: @user3163495 then you just need to provide a private constructor. And use some kind of Singleton / Factory pattern. (and / or by using interfaces as an answer below) The fact that you create a private  class means that noone is supposed to see this class. Here you apparently want the class to be known by others, just not instantiated.

Comment: Had the very same requirement before. The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1664793/4430204)

Comment: But why do you care if they create an instance or not? As for encapsulation I agree that is important but that does not mean hide constructors of all your types and make types nested. A better example of how to encapsulate would be to use a property with a private setter instead of a field for `MyField`.

Comment: In the linked question I added my own answer for generic private clases too =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict access to nested class member to enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664793/how-to-restrict-access-to-nested-class-member-to-enclosing-class)

Comment: Why is class `Inner` a nested class in the first place? Does it need access to the private members of `Outer`?

Comment: Why must `Inner` only be instantiable from inside `Outer`?  Do you not trust your coworkers to use your class correctly?

Comment: Trusting is good, but not trusting is better =) (just a joke)

Comment: Why are `MyField` and `Message` public fields?  Public fields are usually thought of as a bad practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The typical way to solve this is via an interface:

```
public class Outer
{
    public IInner Inner = new Inner();
    public interface IInner { ... }

    private class Inner: IInner { ... }
}
```

`IInner` need not be nested, any choice is viable.

An interesting variation of this pattern is when the nested classes inherit from the outer class. This is a pretty handy code structure that allows really elegant solutions:

```
public abstract class Outer
{
     public static Outer GetOuter(...)
     {
         if (someConditionMet) return new InnerSpecialized1();
         return new InnerSpecialized2();
     } 

     private Outer() { ... } //avoids anyone extending Outer

     private class InnerSpecialized1: Outer { ... }
     private class InnerSpecialized2: Outer { ... }
}
```

Comment: The pattern in the second code sample is one of my favourites.

Comment: @EricLippert I seem to recall reading one of your blogs where you use it in a really cool way but I can’t find it now.

Comment: @EricLippert Just for reference and general knowledge, does this pattern has (a) commonly used name ?

Comment: @InBetween: I don't think I've blogged about it but I have mentioned this pattern in other SO answers on this topic.

Comment: @Pac0: I don't know of a common name for this pattern. I call it the "nested class factory pattern", but that's just me.

Comment: @InBetween How would I access, say, a member of InnerSpecialized1 if InnerSpecialized1 is private? This does not work: var MyObj = Outer.GetOuter(); Console.WriteLine(MyObj.SomeMember);

Comment: @user3163495 the public surface is  defined by the outer class. The nested classes either override  behavior or implement abstract members. The consumer sees only one class; `Outer`, he knows nothing about the private nested classes.

Comment: @EricLippert I was slighlty mistaken (this is vintage stuff...we're getting old). You do use a very similar pattern in one of your series; outer and inner classes all implement a common interface: [Immutability in C# Part Three: A Covariant Immutable Stack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/12/06/immutability-in-c-part-three-a-covariant-immutable-stack/)

Comment: @InBetween: Good find! I had forgotten that I'd used that pattern there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to expose the field's getter only and construct the instance within the class:

```
public class Outer
{
    public Outer()
    {
        MyField = new MyField();
    }
    public Inner MyField {get; private set;}
}

public class Inner
{        
    internal Inner()
    {
    }
    public string Message = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: internal just limits callers of the constructor to being in the same assembly

Comment: @Dave: And only your coworkers can access it. If you coworkers are abusing your code then take that up with them *in code review*.  That's what code review is for.