# How to access a variable declared in a page to a inner class?

Tags: c#, class, uwp

I want to access a variable which is declared as public in Main class to a new class created within the same page. I have done like below. But cant access the variable in that class

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{ 
    public bool is_arrived = false;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        bool is_arrived=true;
        CallingWebServices asyn_task = new CallingWebServices();
    }
    public class CallingWebServices
    {
        //want to access variable "is_arrived" here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict access to nested class member to enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664793/how-to-restrict-access-to-nested-class-member-to-enclosing-class)

Comment: Why are you creating a nested class in a Page? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you should use constructor injection and pass the value of is_arrived to CallingWebServices.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{ 
    public bool is_arrived = false;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        bool is_arrived=true;
        CallingWebServices asyn_task = new CallingWebServices(is_arrived);
    }
    public class CallingWebServices
    {
         private bool _isArrived;
         public CallingWebServices(bool isArrived)
         {
            _isArrived=isArrived;
         }
        //want to access variable "is_arrived" here.
    }
}
```

One problem with this approach is that is_arrived value will loose sync if you change it in the parent class. So other approach is to pass the reference of the parent class to the inner class.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{ 
    public bool is_arrived = false;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        bool is_arrived=true;
        CallingWebServices asyn_task = new CallingWebServices(this);
    }
    public class CallingWebServices
    {
         private MainPage _Instance;
         public CallingWebServices(MainPage instance)
         {
            _Instance=instance;
         }
        //Access variable "instance.is_arrived" here.
     }
}
```

However such practices should be discouraged and should be eliminated by having a better design approach.