# Avoid Access to Constructor of nested Class

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class, inner-classes, class-visibility

here a rougth code example to my problem:

```
class FooMaster
{
    private static FooChildBase GetFooChild(int number)
    {
        switch(number)
        {
            case 1:
                return new FooChild1();
            case 2:
                return new FooChild2();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("...");    
        }
    }

    public static string GetFooChildText1Value(int number)
    {
        FooChildBase fooChild = GetFooChild(number);

        return (fooChild?.Text1) ?? throw new NullReferenceException("...");
    }

    ...

    class FooChild1 : FooChildBase
    {
        internal override string Text1 { get; } = "Test"

        public static void Test()
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }

    class FooChild2 : FooChildBase
    {
        internal override string Text1 { get; } = "Test"
    }
 
    abstract class FooChildBase
    {
        internal abstract string Text1 { get; }
    }
}
```

What i want to accomplish:

You should:

- only be able to get to Text1 if you call 'GetFooChildText1Value' from another class then FooMaster
- be able to access the values and constructors of FooChild1 and FooChild2 in FooMaster
- not be able to call the constructor of FooChild1 or FooChild2 from outside FooMaster
- --> also not be able to see the properties of FooChild1 or FooChild2 from outside FooMaster

EDIT:

The Types FooChild1 and FooChild2 *must be known from outside* because you need to be able to call individual public static methods directly (I don't want to make methods that only call the next method)

Comment: Its hard to see where you are going with this, what you actually want to achieve or why. Yes private and internal would solve "some" of your issues, but I fear there are far bigger design issues here we might be washing over

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict access to nested class member to enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664793/how-to-restrict-access-to-nested-class-member-to-enclosing-class)

Comment: You might also achieve more of what you want by only declaring a visible *interface* and keeping your classes entirely hidden.

Comment: @Cid i tried that. Even with the Class, Contructor and Properties internal I am able to access the Contructor and such the Properties of my nested classes :/

Comment: Sounds like `FooChild1` and `FooChild2` should be `private`?

Comment: @Sweeper they cant. The Type must be known to access for example FooMaster.FooChild1.Test(). My only goal is to make the Contructor available in FooMaster but not from outside

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Because of the FooChildBase inheritances being individual I cant use an interface or am I not getting it? Wouldn't all FooChildBase inheritances had to implement the individual method if I'd use a public interface ?

Comment: Did you _try_ marking them as private? "Private" means only accessible within the class in which they are declared in, which in this case is `FooMaster`. That seems like exactly what you want. See Adrian Efford's answer. It shows exactly what I mean.

Comment: As i allready said. They can't be private because the Type must be known. The Cunstructor should only be accessed by the parent of the nested class, but not from the outside. I cant inherit FooMaster from FooChild because there's no multi inheritance in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

In the End I created another class-library and defined the constructor as internal. That way it's only accessable in this assembly.

The proposed interface solution could also have worked, but I would have had to create a separate interface for each class.

Thanks for all the quick answers!